# Calculating Value Count and Percentage

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table
[Currently Enrolled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLJg5.png)

The table is basically to get an idea of how many supporters, undecided, and opposition they were. Then once I get the count I wanted to then do another calculation to find out what that percentage was.

Essentially what I want to be able to do is:

1. Count the total number of supporters:
   SELECT count(*) AS 'SUPPORTERS' FROM `CURRENTLY ENROLLED` WHERE
   `status` = 'Supporter'
   results were 13
2. Count the total number of opposition:
   SELECT count(*) AS 'OPPOSITION' FROM `CURRENTLY ENROLLED` WHERE `value` = 'Opposition'
   results were 11
3. Count the total number of undecided persons using a similar statement:
   SELECT count(*) AS 'UNDECIDED' FROM `CURRENTLY ENROLLED` WHERE `value` = 'Undecided'
   results were 5

So with the count, I can see that they're 29 total individuals. I wanted to be able to get the percentage of each of them separately. Something like
13/29 * 100 = 44% 
11/29 * 100 = 37% 
5/29 * 100 = 17%

However, I am lost on how to write this query.

Hope I am making this clear as to the intentions.

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_count and post what you have so far

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO! I would recommend reading through [SO tour page](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and through SO help center on [how to ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After that try editing this question according to those guides.

Comment: This site is not a code-writing service. We can help you with *specific* questions about *your* code, ideally accompanied by an [MCVE]. Please show what you have tried, because this site expects some research by the asker and usually showing your attempt at a solution, even if it has errors, clarifies what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [CTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) for the total and group by status for the percentage:

```
with cte as (select count(*) as cnt from `currently enrolled`)
select status, sum(100)/cnt
from `currently enrolled`, cte
group by 1
```

Comment: appreciate it this seems to have worked..